# liquid triangles

Tags: triangles, kinematics

note: for simplicity the 2-dimensional case is described here. a similar situation could be treated in higher dimensions.

liquids are distinguished by their ability to change form whilst retaining constant volume. a *liquid triangle* in $\mathbb{R}^2$ shares this behaviour.

let $A(t),B(t),C(t)$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we will suppress time co-ordinates  in the notation, to preserve simplicity. the rate of change of $A$ with time will be denoted by $\dot A$, etc.

for any points $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ define $\mathbf{e}_{XY}$ to be a unit vector in the direction $XY$

in addition to the congruent displacements corresponding to movements describable as instantaneous translations and rotations the area  $|ABC|$ of a triangle $ABC$, is also invariant under a shift of $A$ along $\mathbf{e}_{BC}$, and similarly for the other sides.

let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \kappa $ be scalar functions of $t,A,B,C$ and let $\mathbf{e}$ be a unit vector depending on the same variables, and set:

$$ \dot A = \alpha\; \mathbf{e}_{BC}+\kappa \mathbf{e} \\
 \dot B = \beta\; \mathbf{e}_{CA}+\kappa \mathbf{e}  \\
 \dot C = \gamma\; \mathbf{e}_{AB}+\kappa \mathbf{e}  \\
$$

**Q**: do these equations define a trajectory for which $|ABC|$ remains invariant? are any restrictions required on the functions defining the motion?

auxiliary question: instantaneous rotation is not catered for in this simplistic description. this would be fairly easy to remedy in the 2-D case, but how should one improve the formulation to remedy this deficiency for the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking in general is this:  Let $X_i(t)$ be the coordinates of the vertices of an $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  What functions can we allow for the $X_i(t)$ so that the volume is preserved.  If this is general enough for you, and not TOO general, the answer is happily elegant.  You need the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix whose $i^{\text{th}}$ column is $X_i(t) - X_0(t)$ to be constant.

Comment: that is indeed a happily elegant solution, and I am grateful for you having pointed it out. I was too immersed in the detail of my initial idea to think of it ;-) as your "not too general" remark indicates, you perhaps realized I was primarily wondering about programming a graphical representation of the 2-D kinematics - I mentioned the n-dimensional problem as an afterthought. the vanishing determinant does not of itself suggest a **symmetrically** presented parametrization. I think it is now a case of "back to the drawing board"